# Debug desctope pref pane application for mac os x

Tags: macos

Can anyone explain how can I debug  pref pane application for mac. Is it possible from xcode or I should install some addition application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't run Preference Pane application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375698/cant-run-preference-pane-application)